# <script> and @Url.Content(this.VirtualPath).Replace(".cshtml", ".ts")

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, typescript

I got a normal path:

```
<script src="~/Views/path/path/01/test.js"></script>
```

and a generated path:

```
<script src="@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath).Replace(".cshtml",".ts")"></script>
```

Both show me the correct path in the html, but only one of them is visible in network traffic(the first one).

How can I make the "generated path" working and why only the first is working ?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Why do you want to include typescript on a web page?

Comment: I have two different file types in the same folder(e.g.: `test.ts` and `test.cshtml`) and I want to work with them.  The only difference between them is the file extension and I wanted to include them in a genereic way without always typing the name of the type script file. The type script will do the binding and loading data from the backend.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to compile `.ts` to `.js` and include the JS file. Anyway, my first question again: what does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: You are right it should have been `<script src="@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath).Replace(".cshtml",".js")"></script>`. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath).Replace(".cshtml",".ts")"></script>
```

with the second ", you are terminating the string from script-source.

What you can do is replace the "-sign with another character (for example ' or \"):

```
<script src="@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath).Replace('.cshtml','.ts')"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath).Replace(\".cshtml\",\".ts\")"></script>
```

Comment: Do you know what Razor syntax is? Don't pay attention to how Stack Overflow (or rather, Google Prettify) renders the code; the code shown will just work in Razor.